# Xamarin Forms watch ViewModel property from .xaml.cs class

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, binding, xamarin.forms

As the title suggests, on Xamarin Forms, I am trying to watch from a View when a property on the ViewModel changes.

This is my ViewModel class

```
public class RegisterViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public bool AutomaticVerificationDone { get; set; }

    public ICommand AutomaticVerification
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(async () =>
            {
                AutomaticVerificationDone = true;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("AutomaticVerificationDone"));
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Register.xaml.cs class

```
public partial class Register : ContentPage
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty AutomaticVerificationDoneProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(AutomaticVerificationDone), typeof(bool), typeof(Register), false);
    public bool AutomaticVerificationDone
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AutomaticVerificationDoneProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(AutomaticVerificationDoneProperty, value);
            if (value)
                accessButton.Opacity = 1;
            else
                accessButton.Opacity = 0.8f;

        }
    }

    public Register()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
        this.BindingContext = new RegisterViewModel();
    }
}
```

Doing in this way nothing happens.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bindable properties don't use your setter; they go directly through the bindable property system.

Instead, you need to [pass a `propertyChanged` callback](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties/#Detecting_Property_Changes) to `BindableProperty.Create`.

But actually, you should bind `Opacity` in your XAML (using a converter) instead.